# Rubymine Cannot Create Ruby SDK Unable to read RbConfig from the specified interpreter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, docker-compose, rubymine

I'm trying to set up a Remote Ruby Interpreter within RubyMine to permit debugging of a Docker-Compose container from within RubyMine.  I have the docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile available within the project's home directory.

When I go to RubyMine | File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Ruby SDK and Gems, I click '+' to add a new interpreter, select Remote Interpreter or Version Manager and retrieve the form.  I select Docker Compose and Service Web.  The Ruby or Version Manager path is simply "ruby".  When I click "OK", I get the following messages:

```
Creating Ruby SDK
Loading RbConfig for C:/tools/ruby31/bin/ruby.exe
Cannot Create Ruby SDK
Unable to read RbConfig from the specified interpreter
```

I have debugged the problem and an providing this question and answer to record the issue.

The original project is provided by Docker as [sample_rails_app](https://github.com/JetBrains/sample_rails_app).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the the Ruby or Version Manager path is actually created by docker-compose.  It is not created until you have successfully created the container using:

```
docker-compose up
```

Once the container exists, then you can create the Remote Ruby Interpreter and use the RubyMine debugger for the app.

Comment: This will be most likely improved and fixed with the fix from the following issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-31441/rake-dbmigrate-fails-with-docker-compose-SDK so could you please follow it in order to be notified about the Available in version.

Comment: I'm facing same issue even after doing `docker-compose up` and ensuring all containers are up.

Comment: Did you see the comment from JetBrains above?  Did that help?